# Extending lines to their Bounding Box in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, line, extents, extend

How to extend lines to Bounding Box in QGIS as in the following image:

[image]
Figure 1: Lines

[image]
Figure 2: Lines extended to Bounding Box

Link to Shapefile of Bounding Box: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jsJ8m2dG0DNwF1jepxpWzwfUVI5sVJJe?usp=sharing

Link to shapefile of lines: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BQvrMiPillL5ubYsDHfEyoV9st12z0E9?usp=sharing

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

Use this expression with [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) or [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) (see here for [details and differences between these two options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)) - the expression is adapted to the data you provided (layer name: `'Bounding Box'`, distance to extend the line: `65`):

```
intersection (
    extend (
        $geometry,65,65
    ),
    geometry (
        get_feature_by_id(
            'Bounding Box',0
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It may not be the most elegant way. However, you use  ["Extend line"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#extend-lines) to extend lines by the distance of the longest edge of the polygon.

[image]

The output looks like this and you can clip by Polygon with the ["Intersection"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#intersection) tool.

[image]

And the output looks like this
[image]

Comment: @babel Can I have your comments on the question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383999/how-to-calculate-optimum-buffer-distance-for-different-groups-of-parallel-close